# Effects package: Error using GLM binomial model

Tags: r, glm

I have been using the Effects package quite successfully in the past with lme4 but now I am stuck with a really simple example using glm. When fitting a binomial glm and then plotting the interaction using Effect I get an error message `"Error in Analyze.model(focal.predictors, mod, xlevels, default.levels,:the following predictor is not in the model: Freq*Gp"`. Below is a simple example that illustrates my problem.

Thanks for your help.

```
Gp<-c(rep("A",20),rep("B",20))
Freq<-c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(1,10),rep(2,10))
Resp<-sample(c(0,1),40, replace=T)
data<-data.frame(Gp)
data$Freq<-Freq
data$Resp<-Resp

m2<-glm(Resp~Freq*Gp, data,family=binomial)
eff<-Effect("Freq*Gp",m2)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the help section: focal.predictors for Effect is asking for a character vector of predictors. For interactions, it's just a matter of supplying a vector of both main effects.

```
eff <- Effect(c('Freq', 'Gp'), m2)
```

giving

```
Freq*Gp effect

              Gp
Freq          A   B
  1   0.4000000 0.3
  1.2 0.4196106 0.3
  1.4 0.4394784 0.3
  1.6 0.4595421 0.3
  1.8 0.4797378 0.3
  2   0.5000000 0.3
```

Comment: Thanks, quoted interaction terms worked just fine until now but that's certainly a better way of doing it.